# Polymorphic association data storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

Can someone explain how data is stored in polymorphic association.

e.g., If I have comments, cases, case steps table.
Comments table is link:

```
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true
```

Cases table is link:

```
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

Case steps table is like:

```
  belongs_to :case, class_name: 'Case', foreign_key: 'case_id'
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

Goen through the links form rails casts and many other links... But not getting the clear understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comments will be like

```
id | user_id | commentable_type | commentable_id | value
--------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | Case             | 1              | fdsfdsfsdf
2  | 1       | CaseStep         | 1              | dasdfs
```

cases table will be like

```
id | case_name
--------------
1  | abc
```

case_steps table will be like

```
id | case_step_name | case_id 
-------------------------------
1  | abc            | 1
```

In Comment table , commentable_type column will store the class name to which it is polymorphic associated and commentable_id is the id of the record of the class(table). In the above case it might be 'Case' or 'CaseStep'